# python corpus: error reported when loading dictionary : 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'doc2bow'

Tags: python, django, dictionary, corpus, gensim

I have to admit I am not a programmer, but I am in charge of deployment. Now I met a big problem. 
In our production environment, the loading of corpus dictionary always fails and the error is

```
  File "/django/rcxue/osqa/rcxue/QuestMatchV2.py", line 121, in loadCorpus
    corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in corpus_m] 

  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'doc2bow'
```

However, the same codes work fine in both our test environment and in developer's local environment. 
I make test server connect to production database and the loading works, which means the database is ok.

I checked every setting file in every directory.The files required are all there and all 'path' are ok. I re-installed all the dependencies frozen from test environment. But I am unable to find the root cause.

May anyone give me some advice how should I proceed my troubleshooting.

Comment: That means `dictionary` is none. Did you forget to load a fixture or something? Looks like dictionary is build on some data, which might not be present. Might be a good idea to get in touch with the developer, and see what might be the cause for the dict to be `None`

Comment: ..or you can look at the file in questions and find where dictionary is being loaded from. It starts out being initialized to None value and then it should get assigned a new value but that doesn't happen for some reason.